# how to updating a field in one table using a count from another table in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
update aamonday_day  
   set ONE = (select count(*) 
                from aday3import 
               where first= 1 
                 and day_of_the_week like 'MON%')
```

no row are updated

however when I run this command:

```
select count(*) 
  from aday3import 
  where first= 1 
    and day_of_the_week like 'MON%'
```

the count is 71

I want to update the table `aamonday` field ONE with 71

Comment: Please can you provide a sample of the data currently in aamonday_day (with column heads).

Comment: there might be no records on the `aamonday_day` table

Comment: Are you providing any where clause for update statement.If yes Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Gian, if there are no rows in table, then you will not be able to update  any columns.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    col1     NUMBER,
    col2     VARCHAR2 (256)
);
```

**Table created**

```
UPDATE  t1
    SET col2 =
                (SELECT  COUNT (*)
                    FROM     employees);
```

**0 rows updated**

```
INSERT INTO   t1
      VALUES   (1, 'jack');
```

**1 row inserted**

```
UPDATE  t1
    SET col2 =
                (SELECT  COUNT (*)
                    FROM     employees);
```

**1 row updated**

Comment: Thanks both @Gian and Polppan. That was the issue. The insert did the job.